# Getting data from schema in psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to connect to Postgres database inside my Python app.
I use psycopg2 library.

If I execute select statement like this:

```
cursor.execute("""select schema_name from information_schema.schemata;""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

and I get :

```
[('DB_FZ',), ('DB_FZ_TEMP',), ...]
```

but if I execute statement

```
cursor.execute("""select * from DB_FZ.d_results;""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

I get error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: schema "db_fz" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from DB_FZ.d_results;
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema name is in uppercase, you should put it in double quotes:

```
cursor.execute("""select * from "DB_FZ".d_results;""")
```

See also [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20878932/1995738)